# Can Zeromq curve authentication mode co-exist with md5 authentication mode?

Tags: zeromq, zeromq-auth

I have a requirement where the present zqromq md5 authentication method has to be moved to curve authentication method. However there can still be clients using the old md5 authentication method in the topology. That means some clients will keep supporting older md5 authentication method whereas some clients will upgrade to the new curve authentication method. So is it possible for an zeromq server to set ZMQ_TCP_MD5SIG and ZMQ_CURVE_SERVER as well on the same socket (this happens to be a ZMQ_ROUTER socket)?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. So the authentication method is configured per socket and not on zmq context. So one router socket can be configured as MD5 authenticated and the other router socket can be configured to use CURVE authentication. Both options can't be enabled on the same socket. So this two sockets and two ports respectively.